How to keep part of a list in R based on it satisfying a condition?
I have a list of tibbles that I've downloaded from a website here:
library(rvest)
ContractHistory <- read_html("https://overthecap.com/player/a-j-mccarron/3103")
ContractHistory <- ContractHistory %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)  

I am looking to keep a single one of those tibbles based on a specific column name existing in it, "status".
To do so, I've (unsuccessfully) tried:
for (i in 1:length(ContractHistory)) {
  if("Status" %in% names(ContractHistory[['i']])==FALSE) {
    ContractHistory[['i']] <- NULL
  }
}  

To me this says check whether the first tibble has a column name status, which it does, and so does nothing.  Then the next iteration checks the second tibble for a column name status, finding it doesn't, which should prompt it to erase that tibble (and same thing for 3,4,5).  But something within it isn't getting passed through and the original list remains unmodified.

You can use  !("Status" %in% names(ContractHistory[['i']]))) instead of "Status" %in% names(ContractHistory[['i']])==FALSE)

Make a boolean vector of which tibbles to keep, then subset with []:
ContractHistory[sapply(ContractHistory, \(x) "Status" %in% names(x))]

(sapply() here iterates over the elements of ContractHistory and tests each one using the anonymous function defined by \(x)...)
You can see that:
> sapply(ContractHistory, \(x) "Status" %in% names(x))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE


The function keep from the purrr package is perfect for this. If you try to access Status column in all the tibbles, where a tibble does not have this particular column, you will get NULL. You can then use keep to only keep the tibbles that return non-NULL.
library(purrr)

ContractHistory %>% 
  keep(function(x) !is.null(x$Status))

UPD: The above solution returns warnings when column Status is not found in other tibbles (but the solution is still valid). The solution below uses @PGSA's "Status" %in% names(x) predicate, but still uses keep:
ContractHistory %>% 
  keep(function(x) "Status" %in% names(x))


Using grepl.
> ContractHistory[grepl("Status", lapply(ContractHistory, names))]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 9 × 11
  Team    `Contract Type` Status       `Year Signed`   Yrs Total  APY   Guarantees `Amount Earned` `% Earned` `Effective APY`
  <chr>   <chr>           <chr>                <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>           <chr>      <chr>          
1 Bengals Drafted         Expired               2014     4 $2,40… $600… $181,652   $2,305,299      96.0%      $576,325       
2 Bills   UFA             Traded                2018     2 $10,0… $5,0… $4,900,000 $0              0.0%       $0             
3 Raiders UFA             Terminated            2018     2 $10,0… $5,0… $4,900,000 $900,000        9.0%       $900,000       
4 Texans  SFA             Expired               2019     1 $3,00… $3,0… $2,500,000 $3,000,000      100.0%     $3,000,000     
5 Texans  UFA             Expired               2020     1 $4,00… $4,0… $3,750,000 $4,000,000      100.0%     $4,000,000     
6 Falcons UFA             Expired               2021     1 $1,21… $1,2… $137,500   $1,212,500      100.0%     $1,212,500     
7 Bengals Practice        Renegotiated          2023     1 $306,… $306… $0         $0              0.0%       $0             
8 Bengals Practice        Elevated              2023     1 $289,… $289… $0         $0              0.0%       $0             
9 Bengals SFA             Terminated            2023     1 $1,16… $1,1… $0         $388,333        33.3%      $388,333   

